# Android library: activeandroid index and unique annotation not available

Tags: java, android, activeandroid

As [activeandroid](https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid) library suggests, when declaring a model class object to use annotation unique and index annotation parameters for unique constraint and indexing for a column respectively [here](https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/wiki/Creating-your-database-model),

```
/**activeandroid imports**/
import com.activeandroid.annotation.Column;
import com.activeandroid.Model;
....
@Table(name="Product")
public class Product extends Model{
    ...
    /**issue: index is not a valid parameter for Column annotation**/
    @Column(name = "Category", index = true)
    public String category;
    ...
}
```

I tried to implement this but the annotation parameters **index** or **unique** are not available in the library.
I am using version 3.0 jar 
Tried version3.1 beta also,same issue there.
While 3.1 is the latest jar available, am I missing something? Please suggest a solution to create indexes when using activeandroid library.
Thanks

Comment: deleting `.jar` file from `libs` folder and adding `compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'` solved my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are extending the Model in your Category Class

```
public class Category extends Model {}
```

if no, please post the entire Class and Error log.

Comment: Thanks zhakid, I have done the same. Because IDE does not let me write the index = true as column annotation does not have index parameter available in the activeandroid library. So it doesn't compile. Were you able to set this up successfully?

Comment: Hi, yes i was able to do it,  do you import the correct annotation? check your imports and let me know. plz edit you question with the class and error log that you have.

Comment: Hi, I am importing com.activeandroid.annotation.Column. Please check the edited question for more details.

Comment: see everything alright, try to add the library via Gradle or Maven, i dont know if u are using a wrong Jar. if not plz put the complete error log to see what it happening.

Comment: I have tried both of the jar files available here https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/downloads

Comment: That library last update was 2012!!! u are using Android Studio or Eclipse?
if android studio in you build.gradle add this dependencies { 
compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'}

Comment: and delete the jar from the library

Comment: if u doesn't use android studio here is the jar http://www.filedropper.com/activeandroid-310-snapshot

Comment: Hi, I am using Android Studio. So com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT has the updated code? version name is same 3.1.0 though. Will try this solution. Thanks

Comment: Yes.  Try that if it work for you i'll update my answer so u can mark as correct.

Comment: same issue...
any solution?

Comment: Aston do you try my approach?